# Unable to fine Meta data URL for configuring Salesforce saas application

Tags: salesforce, saas, salesforce-service-cloud

I am not able to find remore metadata URL for configuring salesforce saas application. like for example, in many orginisations, it is https://{entity}/saml/metadata for example, in github its. https://github.com/orgs/template-test/saml/metadata. can you please help me in finding that? my domain is https://emumba8.my.salesforce.com/ but https://emumba8.my.salesforce.com/saml/metadata is not working.